# how can i modify the code of java jar file running in server

Tags: java, server, jar

i have created an springboot application and JNDI configuration is given by using @bean method
i deployed the jar file of my application in jalastic server
but there error in log file is showing wrong host
i dont want to again compile jar file in my eclipse ide and then deploy the jar in server

## question--is there any option to modify the java file while it is running in the server

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not possible because Java compiles its code to .class files which are very close to machine language. Technically it is possible to adjust a .class file but that would require you to understand the Java bytecode. For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are options to do this - you can adjust java bytecode as mentioned or play with java class loader - in other words you don't want to do it :) Instead maybe you can store some of you config in properties file and adjust the properties only? Then you would just need to restart your or introduce a mechanism that reads the properties by every usage?

Comment: i want to change the database url ,but i have given url inside .java file using @bean method. but in jalastic dashboard, it is not allowing me to open the deployed jar file. is there any easy solution??